# How to make container that doesn't contain sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for the best solution to make container that contains only right-side of my webpage ( because I have sidebar on my left side)

I've tryed to put for example on 80% of width on .content, but obviously it deletes 20% from right side instead of left.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <button type="button" id="skidaj" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Download CV</button> 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
background-image: url("moja.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0.7;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
padding-left: 170px;
clear:both;
float: left;
        }

  #sideNav {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100vh;
  }
```

`.content` should be container only on right-side, but it affects my sidebar aswell.

Comment: Please edit your HTML example to show the `#sideNav`.  All I see right now is your `.content` container with a button inside of it. We need to see how the `#sideNav` comes into play, in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a main div having position relative and create your sidebar and content inside it. Now you can position your container and sidebar anywhere inside the main div checkout this snippet:

```css
#main{
  width:100%;
  postion:relative;
}
.sidebar{
  position:absolute;
  width:20%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  float:left;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
.container{
  width:80%;
  height:100px;
  background:#ccc;
  position:absolute;
  left:20%;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="sidebar"> 
    
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    
  </div>
</div>
```